# Error when deploying using CDI on Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, cdi

I was playing around with CDI on Glassfish but did not get too far.
As soon as I put an empyt beans.xml in /WebContent/META-INF I get the following error:

> cannot Deploy CDI_Example
>   Deployment Error for module: CDI_Example: Exception while loading the app : org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: WELD-001201 Error loading beans.xml URL: null

The Weld documentation says the file may be empty but it looks like Glassfish v3 expects anything within the file.

Anybody got an idea?

Thx

Comment: you may want to pen an issue against glassfish... http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH to get started.  You will probably need to attach your sample app and provide a bit more details about your environment.

Comment: please approve the answer of @Yakov Fain. I had the same issue as you and it answers worked. beans.xml should be in WEB-INF(along with the *web.xml 's file) rather than in META-INF

Comment: did you clean dist/ and build/ directories and restarted server and recompiled the project? GlassFish often doesn't recognize xml changes of this type and needs to be restarted.

Answer (score 6):

"Empty" does not mean that beans.xml should be completely empty. 
It means that you don't have to specify anything, but it should at least contain the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Comment: Well, should have mentioned that my beans.xml is well formed, but contains no additional elements. Anyway, I'm still stuck on this issue and cant find a solution. Can anybody provide a working example?

Answer (score 2):

The beans.xml can be completely empty. But if you are creating a Web application, it has to be located not in META-INF, but in WEB-INF dir.

Comment: "The beans.xml can be completely empty." Adding the `beans` element as indicated by ifischer solved my problem. This of course implies that beans.xml cannot be empty.